# How to post dynamic dropdown value in php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have using the following code for my dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" name="device" id="device" onChange="getBrand(this.value);">
<option selected name="device" id="device" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
</select>
```

for form submit, i have used this code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $device = $_POST['device'];
}
```

I want to get selected value in button submit, currently I got the id instead of value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `$row['name']` as value of your option

```
<select class="form-control" name="device" id="device" onChange="getBrand(this.value);">
    <option selected name="device" id="device" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
</select>
```

If you can't change option value, you could use jQuery:

```
$("#your_form").submit( function () {
    var option_text = $('#device').find(":selected").text();
    $("#your_form").append('<input name="selected_option_text" type="hidden" value="' + option_text + '">');
});
```

This will add a input field with name "selected_option_text" before submit. So you will find it in your receiving script

Comment: i've used ajax based dropdown so i need to mention id there, is there is any other option........thanks

Comment: Sorry, but option text is not submitted by form. It could be done with javascript/jQuery if it's ok for you

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data-attribute on your option 
for example

```
data-value = $row['name']
```

Then get the data-attr in your Javascript/jQuery